# nexus indexer (macosx-leopard) issue

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven-2, nexus, indexer

I'm stuck trying to add  org.nakedobjects.prototyping : application, the nexus indexer cant find anything. I've realized that in the url text box doesn't contains the http;//repo1.maven.org/maven2/ address, any clues?

I'm using the latest version of eclipse 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Maven 2.1.0 right? I had the same problem in my Ubuntu box and I guess is a bug. I solved it using Maven 2.0.10